# Magento 2 Get data to admin UI Form without key and collection

Tags: magento2, module, admin, uicomponent, adminform

Is there a way to get data from a DataProvider to my UI Form component, without having a collection or a key?

My DataProvider currently only has a "getData" function and the form is rendered, but I can't get any values to my form.

My objective is to connect to an API to get the values to be used in the form. 
This is my DataProvider:

```
<?php

namespace Invoicing\Moloni\Model\Settings;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
{
    public $loadedData;

    public function getData()
    {
        return [];
    }

}
```

And this is my UI Component:

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">moloni_settings_edit.settings_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">moloni_settings_edit.settings_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Settings</item>
    <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
    </item>

    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Invoicing\Moloni\Block\Adminhtml\Settings\Buttons\SaveButton</item>
    </item>

</argument>

<dataSource name="settings_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Invoicing\Moloni\Model\Settings\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">settings_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>

<fieldset name="general">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General settings</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <field name="document_set_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Document set</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">document_set_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

After exploring the Magento code, I got to the form.php that has the following:

```
$id = $this->getContext()->getRequestParam($this->getContext()->getDataProvider()->getRequestFieldName(), null);
```

This $id in my case is null because I don't need to have any id.

Then I end up with a empty $dataSource

```
if (isset($data[$id])) {
        $dataSource = [
            'data' => $data[$id]
        ];
    } elseif (isset($data['items'])) {
        foreach ($data['items'] as $item) {
            if ($item[$item['id_field_name']] == $id) {
                $dataSource = ['data' => ['general' => $item]];
            }
        }
    }
```

In my form I will need to have data from a external API (options) and selected values (those are stored in a database table).

What's the best way to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing for now, was adding a "id" to the url with the value of "1", and in the getData, I returned it like this:

```
public function getData()
{
    $values = ['1' => ['document_set_id' => 991]]
    return $values;
}
```

And I manage to get the values.

But after searching for a better solution in Magento core modules, I took for example the Users module.

That module extends **\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic** 
Is there any problem using that class even if it says its "Deprecated"?

I can't really seem to get my UI Components to work without this "hack".

Answer (score 0):

You must create dataprovider like that
app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/DataProvider
with code

```
    <?php
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Model;
 
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
{    
    public function getData()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

and use it in your ui_component layout
app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/test_test_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">namespace_module_form.namespace_module_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">namespace_module_form.namespace_module_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Rfq Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">namespace_module_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">Back</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Back</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">back</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/index</item>
            </item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">Save</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Save</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">save primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/save</item>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="namespace_module_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">namespace_module_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="test/test/save/"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="category_duplicate_details">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Test Options</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="test" formElement="select">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Test Field</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>boolean</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Test Field</label>
                <dataScope>test</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options class="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno"/>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
        </field>            
    </fieldset>
</form>
```